# How can i manimulate the pages added in admin side of wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added two pages  through admin side(About us, privacy policy)

How can i show the 'About us' link in header section and 'privacy policy' link i the footer section of client side, dynamically

Comment: ok, it can do  as

$pages = get_pages('exclude=2,6,8,12,14,16,18,20sort_column=menu_order')

foreach($pages as $page): 
<a href="<?php  echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>" ><?php echo $page->post_title ?></a> |

endforeach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends on the theme you are using. For example, themes can use [wp_list_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) or (in WP3.0) [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) to automatically list all or some pages on your site, the latter having a page on the admin side of things where you can choose which pages you want in each menu defined in the theme.